# Are all complex polynomials without negative powers everywhere differentiable and analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on a problem from a past paper,

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be given by $f(x+iy)=x^3+xy^2+(2x^2y+y)i$. Where is $f$ differentiable? Where is $f$ analytic?

This is my first course in complex analysis. This may be a dumb question, but why is the answer not simply, "Everywhere, because it's a polynomial with no negative powers."? 6 marks are available, which makes me suspicious of such a simple answer.

**Edit 1:** It's just occurred to me that this isn't necessarily a polynomial in $z$.

**Edit 2:** But my course notes have "the sum and product of two differentiable functions is differentiable", so don't we get the same result by $f$ being a combination of polynomials?

**Edit 3:** After some more reading and thinking, I use the CR conditions with the differentiability of $u(x,y)=x^3+xy^2, \; v(x,y)=2x^2y+y$ to get that $f$ is differentiable only at $(x,y)\in\{(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)\}$ and therefore nowhere analytic (since differentiable only at points, not on neighborhoods around them). If someone would like to tell me if I'm right, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Because your $f\colon\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ that maps a complex variable $z\mapsto f(z)$ is not defined as a polynomial in terms of $z$ but rather in terms of the real and imaginary parts of $z$, thus $f$ is not necessarily a polynomial of a complex variable $z$

Comment: Haha looks like you figured it out.

Comment: Whether or not you're right about the determination and/or the reason, you'll need to know definitions and/or theorems about differentiable and analytic (which is defined like three different ways depending on the course/book) to cite when making your argument. Since you mentioned "6 marks", I'm not comfortable helping more.

Comment: Have you done Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I'm aware of them and tried applying them in this case, but my course notes point out that "the fact that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at a certain point is NOT SUFFICIENT to guarantee differentiability at that point", and also my Cauchy-Riemann working led to the unexpected conclusion that $f$ is differentiable only at $0$.

Comment: A function $f=u+vi: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic if and only if it is differentiable and satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: @Don That's an odd phrasing. If it's (complex) differentiable at a point, then it satisfies CR at the point. And (complex) differentiable at a point may not be enough for analyticity.

Comment: @MarkS. 'Since you mentioned "6 marks", I'm not comfortable helping more.' You mean in case I'm in the middle of an exam?

Comment: @MarkS. Just to clarify what I meant. Let $f: \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a map and $z_0 \in \Omega$. $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable at $z_0$ iff $f$ is Fréchet differentiable at $z_0$ and satifies CR at $z_0$. $f$ is analytic at $z_0$ iff $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable at every point of an open neighbourhood of $z_0$ in $\Omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let$$u(x,y)=\operatorname{Re}\bigl(f(x+yi)\bigr)=x^3+xy^2$$and$$v(x,y)=\operatorname{Im}\bigl(f(x+yi)\bigr)=2x^2y+y.$$Then, since $u$ and $v$ have continuous partial derivatives, $f$ is differentiable at a point $x+yi$ if and only if $(x,y)$ is a solution of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, which are$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}3x^2+y^2=2x^2+1\\2xy=-4xy.\end{array}\right.$$This system has four solutions: $(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1)$. Therefore, $f$ is differentiable at four and only four points: $\pm1$ and $\pm i$. So, yes, $f$ is analytic nowhere, since there is no non-empty open set $O$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $O$ is analytic.

Besides, $f$ is *not* a polynomial in $z$. Furthermore, the functions $x+yi\mapsto x$ and $x+yi\mapsto y$ are differentiable nowhere, and therefore the fact that $f(x+yi)$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ is irrelevant.